# Change string encoding of pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I have a DataFrame with a MultiIndex that I want to convert to utf8. Is there a trick that allows you to do something along the lines of `df.index = df.index.str.decode('iso-8859-1').str.encode('utf-8')` (which works on single-level Indexes, but not MultiIndexes)?

Comment: unclear what you're asking but `str.decode` and `str.encode` are methods on `Series` not `Index` objects so you'd need to do `df.index.to_series().str.decode()` and so on

Comment: @EdChum In latest pandas this are also methods on Index, but only not on MultiIndexes, hence the question ..

Comment: @joris yes, you're right I was thinking of some other methods but thinking about it I've use `str.foo` before on `Index` objects. So in this case You'd have to get the unique index values, `decode/encode` and set level values I guess

Comment: @EdChum indeed, something in that direction. The only problem is that this is not very straightforward with the current API ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `str` methods indeed only work on single levels, not on a Multi-Index. So I think there are two ways with dealing with this: a) retrieve the single levels, change them, reconstruct the multi-index, or b) work on it as columns (by resetting the index, and setting it back afterwards.

Using a dummy dataframe for the example:

```
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':['é', 'a', 'b'], 'c':[0.1,0.2,0.3]})

In [7]: df = df.set_index(['a', 'b'])

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
       c
a b
1 é  0.1
2 a  0.2
3 b  0.3
```

For a), you can use `get_level_values` to get the individual levels as Index objects:

```
In [12]: levels = [df.index.get_level_values(i) for i in range(df.index.nlevels)]

In [13]: levels
Out[13]:
[Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64', name=u'a'),
 Index([u'é', u'a', u'b'], dtype='object', name=u'b')]

In [14]: levels[1] = levels[1].str.decode('iso-8859-1').str.encode('utf-8')

In [16]: df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(levels)
```

Or for b), reset the index and set it back afterwards:

```
In [27]: temp = df.reset_index()

In [29]: temp['b'] = temp['b'].str.decode('iso-8859-1').str.encode('utf-8')

In [30]: df = temp.set_index(['a', 'b'])
```

Comment: Thanks, the set-reset method is what I had; one thing that's still a bit inefficient is that you have to check the dtype of each column or the `.str` methods will raise an error.